# Including a Sweave document in R studio?

Tags: r, sweave, rstudio

I created two files Master.Rnw and Child.Rnw as in [this documentation](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/authoring/multiple_rnw_files). To wit:

Master.rnw:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\section{Overview}
This is the overview.

\SweaveInput{Child.Rnw}

\end{document}
```

Child.Rnw:

```
% !Rnw root = Master.Rnw

\section{Analysis}
This is the analysis.

<<analysis>>=
summary(cars)
@
```

I click "Compile PDF" and get "Undefined control sequence" for  \SweaveOpts and  \SweaveInput.

I'm using the latest R Studio (0.98.490).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

The project was set to weave using knitr instead of Sweave.

I went to Tools / Options / Sweave / "Weave Rnw files using" and changed it to Sweave.

That got the documented example to work.